# Selecting text using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the text from the 'Proposal' h3 element that looks like this using Selenium and Python:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aewmw.png)

I've tried using the direct XPATH to the text:
`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="aspnetForm"]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/text()[1]')`

And referencing the H3 element directly:
`//div[@class="col-sm-8"]//h3[1]`

The first returns an error in accessing the element, and the second just prints 'Proposal' rather than the actual text. Is there a way to solve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit the question and update the HTML in the form of text rather than image?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.